# java new file not returning a boolean when part of a conditional

Tags: java, java-io

In my Java program, this creates a directory and returns a boolean true when successful:

```
new File(String.valueOf(subdir)).mkdir();
```

So why does that not work as the second part of this boolean? I.e., the directory does not get created and it does nt return a boolean true.

```
if (!subdir.exists() || new File(String.valueOf(subdir)).mkdir()) {
    logger.error("subdir not created");
}
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting and what's the declaration for `maint`?

Comment: you are mixing "or" with "and". there is nothing wrong with the conditional.

Comment: Besides that, if `subdir` is already a `File`, as the call `subdir.exists()` suggests, there is no sense in doing `new File(String.valueOf(subdir))` instead of just using `subdir` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second condition won't be calculated if the first condition is already `true` and the conditions are joined with OR `||` operator.

Similarly, second condition is not calculated for AND `&&` operator if the first condition is `false`.

It is so called `short circuit` for logical operations - because it does not make sense to continue evaluation of other terms if the result of the expression is already defined:

```
false && any_operand == false
true || any_operand == true
```

So, in your case you need to use `&&` in the condition and possibly use `File::mkdirs()` method to create parent directories if they don't exist:

```
if (!maint.exists() && !maint.mkdirs()) {
    logger.info("no directories {} created", maint);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, it’s better to use NIO: `Files.createDirectories(maint.toPath())` instead of `maint.mkdirs()`, as it will throw exceptions telling you *why* the operation failed.